# How to select row with maximum value in column for each group in HSQL?

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, hsqldb

I have a table named PERSON in an HSQL database like this:

```
NAME(PK) | AGE | CITY   | ... many more here ... | 
--------------------------------------------------
aaa      |  12 |   nyc  | ...
bbb      |  12 |   nyc  | ...
ccc      |  10 |   nyc  | ...
ddd      |  34 |    la  | ...
eee      |  10 |    la  | ...
```

For each city I need to select the record with the maximum age. If for a given city there are multiple records with tied maximum age I still need to select exactly one record for this city (but it can be arbitrarily chosen).

So in the above example I need this result:

```
NAME(PK) | AGE | CITY | ... many more here ... | 
--------------------------------------------------
aaa      |  12 |  nyc | ...
ddd      |  34 |   la | ...
```

and it would be ok if I got bbb instead of aaa, but not ok to get aaa and bbb.

Simply using group by on the city column and max(age) as aggregate function does not work, because this does not allow me to select other columns than age and city as they are not in the aggregate. I tried doing the group by and then joining the result back to the table, but this way I do not manage to get rid of records with duplicate max age. This query:

```
SELECT NAME, CITY, AGE, [... many more here ...] 
FROM ( 
    SELECT max(age) AS maxAge, city 
    FROM PERSON
    GROUP BY CITY
) AS x
JOIN PERSON AS p 
ON p.city = x.city AND p.age = x.maxAge
```

yields:

```
NAME(PK) | AGE | CITY | ... many more here ... | 
--------------------------------------------------
aaa      |  12 |  nyc | ...
bbb      |  12 |  nyc | ...
ddd      |  34 |   la | ...
```

whith two records for nyc where there should be only one.

Comment: How to chose aaa or bbb for NYC?

Comment: it can be arbitrary as long as only one record is selected for each city

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modern SQL alternative to the correlated subquery solution is the LATERAL keyword:

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM PERSON) CITIES, 
 LATERAL 
 (SELECT * FROM PERSON WHERE CITY = CITIES.CITY ORDER BY AGE DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Is this also expected to perform better than the correlated subquery ?

Comment: Speed should be similar. You need an index on CITY for speed.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about order then you can use *correlated* `subquery` :

```
select * 
from PERSON p
where name = (select name 
              from PERSON 
              where CITY = p.City 
              order by AGE desc, name asc -- neglate name if you want arbitrary ordering 
              LIMIT 1);
```

This will select only one name for each city.